# How to incorporate the next result of a query in the query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Suppose you have a **students** table:

```
UID   Grade   Level
------------------
1     Pass      21
2     Fail      25
3     Pass      23
4     Fail      22
5     Pass      25
```

How would you write a Postgres SQL query that:

1. Orders the students by ascending level
2. Calculates the percentage of students at the ***next*** level that have passed

So, in this case:

```
Level    % Passed at next level
-------------------------------------
  21             0%
  22           100%
  23            50%
  25             -
```

Working in Postgres 8.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more than one student per level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
(
      SELECT (SELECT max(level) FROM students "inner" WHERE "inner".level < "outer".level) as Level
           , sum(Case When grade = 'Pass' Then 1.0 Else 0.0 End) / count(*)                as Percentage
        FROM students "outer"
    GROUP BY level
    union all
      SELECT max(level) as Level
           , null       as Percentage
        FROM students
) mylevels
 WHERE level is not null
```

But this is not a pretty code.

I recommend you to create a table level(level int, next_level int) the code would be much more simple.

Comment: The information (`level, next_level`) could easily be calculated with a recent version of (>= 8.4) of PostgreSQL